# Image inside div resizes when window resizes REPONSIVE DESIGN

Tags: css, responsive-design, width

here's my problem / issue / scenario / something that i can't figure out for three hours now.

http://jsfiddle.net/5f6dK/

here's the css:

```
header {
    width:100%;
    height:95px;
    color:#FFF;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    background:#3b5998;
    display:block;
    z-index:99999;
    top:0px;
    border-bottom:1px solid ##133783;
    float:left;
}

.inner-header {
    margin:0px auto !important;
    width:100%;
    height:95px;
    max-width:1400px;
    min-width:700px;
    padding:0 10px 0 10px;
}

.header-logo{
    padding-right:10px;
    width:100% auto;
}

img#header1280-1366 {
    width:100%;
}

.header-logo, .xbdlogo {
    float:left;
}

.header-adsense {
    float:left;
}

.xbdlogo {
    top:-100px;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    overflow:auto;
    margin-right:10px;
}

.header-logo:hover + .xbdlogo {
    top:30px;
}

.header-adsense {
    padding-top:2px;
}
```

It is a website header.

**The Problem:**

The header compose of 3 components, the two header logo and the adsense ads.

I wanna make it responsive, whenever the user re-sizes the window, is it possible if the PNG BENDAGGERS re-sizes to smaller image. I'm having trouble with it. i set the width to 100% but it's not working.

Any suggestion how to do it?

Please help! I appreciate your help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: make the widths in percents i.e `width:30%`, and so on, `height:auto` and the padding and margin 0.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to make it responsive, whenever the user re-sizes the window, is it possible if the PNG BENDAGGERS re-sizes to smaller image. I'm having trouble with it. i set the width to 100% but it's not working.

The image is inside a floated div, which wraps to the size of the image, so in this situation `width: 100%` can only be as large as the image itself. If you didn't float the container, the image would be huge (as width as the blue area) so that's also not what you want.

To be honest, you don't need the image to be responsive, because it's small enough to fit on any screen. However, if you really do want this, you could remove the float on the container and give the image a width of, say, 30%. Then it will scale with the browser.

Be aware, though, that it will stop scaling at 700px, because the `inner-header` div has a min-width of 700px.

Comment: i was doing this because the width of the google ads was fixed to 728px and there's no way to fit the three components without resizing the logo. anyway, you just gave me a great idea. thank you again!!!

Comment: Glad it helped, Kareen. :-)